# How to programmatically invoke the Click event handler of a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, click

I know how to programmatically invoke the event handler of a Button:

```
button1.PerformClick();
```

I would like to do the same for the `Click` event handler of a `TextBox`. The problem is that TextBox does not have a

```
textBox1.PerformClick();
```

Comment: It's just a method like any other; call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *method extraction* (why should we mix *UI* - windows messages and *Business Logic*):

```
//TODO: put a better name here 
private void onMyTextBoxClick() {
  //TODO: relevant code here
}

private void MyTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  onMyTextBoxClick();
}
```

Then you can just call `onMyTextBoxClick`:

```
...
// Same business logic as if MyTextBox is clicked
onMyTextBoxClick();
...
```

**Edit:** If you really want `EventArgs` aruments, just provide them:

```
//TODO: put a better name here 
private void onMyTextBoxClick(TextBox box, EventArgs e) {
  //TODO: relevant code here
}

// Default EventArgs
private void onMyTextBoxClick(TextBox box) {
  onMyTextBoxClick(box, EventArgs.Empty);
}

// Both TextBox and EventArgs are default ones
private void onMyTextBoxClick() {
  onMyTextBoxClick(MyTextBox, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void MyTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  onMyTextBoxClick(sender as TextBox, e);
}
```

Usage:

```
// Default EventArgs
onMyTextBoxClick(myTextBox);

// Custom EventArgs
EventArgs args = ...

onMyTextBoxClick(myTextBox, args);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I also thought about this, but at the other call to onMyTextBoxClick I do not have the EventArgs argument.

Comment: @user2102327: If you really required `EventArgs` you can change `onMyTextBoxClick` signature and provide overloaded versions of `onMyTextBoxClick`, please see my edit